# $ : The term '$' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: django, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to setup django but when I writevthe command an error appears in cmd :
$ django-admin startproject new-app

error :$ : The term '$' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- $ python manage.py startapp chatbot
- ~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You don't need $ in your commands

Comment: The `$` is the command prompt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dollar (`$`) is the command prompt. This is typical in a (Linux) shell. For PowerShell for example it is `PS working-directory>`. You thus don't include the dollar sign. This is often included in code snippets because that is what the terminal will show, and furthermore also makes it clear that this is in the shell.

You thus write `python manage.py startapp chatbot` *without* the dollar.